# UIButton's title property logs correctly but not showing up when adding button as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, subview, addsubview

I have a UIButton that I have created, and I can successfully add it as a subview and see it on the screen. The problem is, when I try using:

```
[myButton setTitle:@"My Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The button does not show a title when I run the app. If I NSLog the button's title after using the above method, it has in fact been set to the title that I'm passing in.

Here's my code. This is inside a UIView subclass. I realize that some of this logic might not belong in a UIView subclass but I'm just trying to get this to work as fast as possible:

```
// Set the view's frame, background color, corner radius
self.frame = CGRectMake(45, 200, 235, 187);
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

// Create the popup's body text label
self.popupBodyTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 150)];
self.popupBodyTextLabel.text = @"Text goes here.";

// Add text view to popup's subviews
[self addSubview:self.popupBodyTextLabel];

// Create ok button
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 143, 120, 44)];
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
myButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
[myButton setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


// Round the button's bottom left corner
UIBezierPath *myButtonMaskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:myButton.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

CAShapeLayer *okButtonMaskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
myButtonMaskLayer.frame = myButton.bounds;
myButtonMaskLayer.path = myButtonMaskPath.CGPath;
myButton.layer.mask = myButtonMaskLayer;


// Add selector to button
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add button to subviews
[self addSubview:myButton];

// Create the background view
self.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
self.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
self.backgroundView.alpha = 0.5f;

// Show our new views
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.backgroundView];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:[MPPopupView shared]];
```

Comment: add any font color for button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for setting button title is right, so use this code to set **title color**

```
   [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```